# :: jQuery KendoDateTimePicker :: Default time = current time + 10 minutes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using KendoDateTimePicker.

**We need to restrict user not to the select past time.**

Eg: **If current time is 2pm, time field should start from 2:10pm**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/ye5mfubp/2/)

```js
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
  value: '',
  min: new Date(),
  format: "dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm tt",
  timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
  interval: 10,
});
```

```css
.wrapper {width:300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.2.829/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/6.7.0/default/default-ocean-blue.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" />
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant, need to restrict user to not to select past time/current time. The time dropdown should show from current time to 10 minutes.
Eg: If current time is 2pm, time field should start from 2:10pm

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `startTime` field instead of the `min` field, which is used to set the minimal date for the date picker.
You can set the mininal time selection to be `now + 10` minutes like this:

```
const startTime = new Date();
startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + 10); // or const startTime = new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000)
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    value: '',
    startTime: startTime,
    format: "dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm tt",
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
    interval: 10,
});
```